# A deciphering Droid

Tags: cipher

The Galactic Republic is in crisis, the Droid Army has intercepted some messages between the republic forces. Help them to decrypt these !

Only basic cipher / encoding method are using here.

1. General Grievous ! I think a Jedi is approaching...

   > 48454C4C4F205448455245

Hint 1

> Just a basic translation.

2. The key can keep you away from death.

   > RSU ASPJAUFFKO BQ P ROPBRKO

Hint 2

> Alphabetical substitution, you just need to find the right key

3. Just chronological

   > TFJBYDU

Hint 3

> 7 letters, for 7 films

*Computing version:*

```
48454C4C4F205448455245
RSU ASPJAUFFKO BQ P ROPBRKO
TFJBYDU
```

Comment: Please, explain your reason when downvoting, after that i can edit my post and don't do the same mistake the next time.

Comment: Maybe you should name the one that downvoted you, otherwise he/she might not realize that you are talking to him/her.

Comment: It's impossible to see who downvoted (see [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts) )

Comment: I did not downvote this puzzle, but many PSE people are not fond of puzzles like this where basically the question is "can you guess the cipher I used?". See https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do/ for advice on how to make cipher questions that might be better received.

Comment: Already read that post, but as i say in my post, maybe i was not clear, but the goal is to find the key not the cipher, i don't ask to try all the cipher but if people are too busy to try at least the most common, they can downvote me, no probleme with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first cipher

> is simply ASCII represented in hex. "HELLO THERE".

The second cipher

> says "THE CHANCELLOR IS A TRAITOR". It looks to me like a standard keyword + rest-of-alphabet substitution cipher, with key PLAGUEIS.

The third cipher

> seems like it plainly has too little information, but pondering the hint leads to the following thought: the relationship between in-universe and out-of-universe chronology for the Star Wars films is given by the numbers 4,5,6,1,2,3,7, and if we move backwards by those numbers of letters in the alphabet from TFJBYDU we get PADAWAN which I take it is the intended answer.

Comment: First and second are good. You're on the way for the third,but it's not a vigenere. Think about chronological.

Comment: Darn, I guess I should've just posted my answers instead of trying to find the 3rd one first... Note that the OP actually says "Just chronological", so I figure it makes sense to take the movies on chronological order, but even then I couldn't make sense of it. I've also tried using the year of release and even length of the titles, but it didn't seem to give anything useful either.

Comment: Yeah, the third seems like a pure "guess what I'm thinking" puzzle. If anyone else wants to put more thought into solving it then I'll happily urge Skyvask to accept their answer in preference to mine; for my part, trying to enumerate the dozens of things ... oh, wait, I've got it. About to update my answer. [EDITED to add:] Now done.

Comment: yeah, thanks to try at least, i will avoid this type of puzlle next time

Comment: Ah obviously... that makes sense. I had the solution of the 3rd one right in front of me while trying to solve it, but I didn't see it :P